# How can I access class constants using `self::` inside an anonymous function defined in a method?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I would like to access a class constant using `self` from within an anonymous function.

```
class My_Class {    
    const  CLASS_CONSTANT = 'test value';
    private function my_function(){     
        $lambda_function = function(){
            echo self::CLASS_CONSTANT;
        };
        $lambda_function();
    }
}
```

When I tried this, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in ...

Is it possible to pass the parent class into the scope of this anonymous function?  Would a `use` statement work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[>> All versions test of PHP 5.4+ way on 3v4l <<](http://3v4l.org/3Y861)

**PHP 5.4+ WAY:**

This has become significantly simpler since PHP 5.4, where `$this` is no longer dirty:

```
class My_Class {
    const CLASS_CONSTANT = 'test value';

    private function my_function() {
        $lambda_function = function() {
            // $this is actually inherited from the parent object, so
            // you don't even need a use() statement
            echo $this::CLASS_CONSTANT;

            // Or just use self, that's inherited too
            echo self::CLASS_CONSTANT;
        };
        $lambda_function();
    }
}
```

**PRE 5.4 WAY:**

Make the anonymous function a closure -- by introducing scoped variables into the function -- and call the constant from that:

```
class My_Class {
    const CLASS_CONSTANT = 'test value';
    private function my_function() {
        $self = $this;
        $lambda_function = function() use ($self) { // now it's a closure
            echo $self::CLASS_CONSTANT;
        } // << you forgot a ;
        lambda_function(); // << you forgot a $
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you can't `use ($this)` YET. They're working on it. I expect it to work in PHP >= 5.4.

Comment: What about calling static methods like static::Func() within the anonymous class? (yes `My_Class::Func()` would work but that's not the point) What's the $this equivalent for static functions?

Comment: You can call `$self::func()`, even if it's protected or private, because you call it from the context of the class itself. I'm not absolutely sure though... Try it out. `$object::static()` is your friend.

Comment: In php 5.5 it's possible to use `self` inside of anonymous functions without using the `use` keyword

Answer (score 8):

afaik anonymous functions are just that.. functions. Not class methods, so scope is out. You can pass the constant as an argument or use My_Class::CLASS_CONSTANT.

Comment: If you don't to reference the class by its name, you can use magic constant `__CLASS__` which can effectively replace your need for `self` in your lambda function.

Comment: That works and I"ll probably use it.  Requires two lines though.  `$class_name = __CLASS__;  $class_name::CLASS_CONSTANT;` because `__CLASS__::CLASS_CONSTANT;` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the self inside an anonymous function, this won't work. What you should do is  use `My_Class::CLASS_CONSTANT` instead of the self reference.

Comment: `private function my_function() use ($any_variable){ ... }` works for any variable except `$this` apparently.  Why doesns't it work with `$this`?

Comment: Because the developers of PHP had difficulty implementing this correctly, afaik. It's available in the upcoming PHP version though (5.4.0).

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Similarly, you can not bind $this to an anonymous function. Just passing the necessary values instead should do the trick though?

```
<?php
class My_Class {
    const  CLASS_CONSTANT = 'test value';
    private function my_function(){     
        $lambda = function( $yourConstant ){
            return $yourConstant;
        };

        return $lambda( self::CLASS_CONSTANT );
    }

    public function test( ) {
        return $this->my_function( );
    }
}

$class = new My_Class( );
echo $class->test( ); // 'test value'
```

Comment: Side note: nothing prevents you from passing $this variable into "use" section of anonymous function. You just need to assign it to intermediary var, say $that = $this, and then function () use ($that) {}, will have reference to current object.